# Cognos - How to send report embedded in email?

Tags: email, cognos

I'm trying to embed a Cognos report in an email message body, with no luck.

I've tried IBM official solution and to unmark "Include a link to the report" and "Attach the report"  in the email options and it didn't work. I've also tried to embed the report using  html tag, but the mail client (Outlook) does not support iframe.

Google searches didn't show anything useful. Does anyone here have another idea without using external tool?

Comment: Check the format of the report... is it HTML?  In order for the embed to work, you must only be running the report in HTML mode.  If you are running multiple versions in one scheduled job (ie. PDF and HTML), then neither will be embedded.

Answer (score 1):

If you attach an HTML output of the report to an email in Event Studio, it's displayed in the email body.

Answer (score 1):

the solution to this is very weird but believe me if you leave the email message body blank ,when you are specifying the to and cc, the subject of the mail etc and chose to attach the report ,the report is displayed in the body of the message when delivered..If you type even a single word in the message body of the schedule then the email is attached.Also only HTML formats are embedded rest all get attached.

i hope this helps .It has always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear the "link to report" but most important LEAVE THE BODY BLANK.

It is stated here: [IBM LINK](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21659766)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ReportOutput() function, you are likely to get an individual email for each output type.